# Invalid escape sequence error when I try to define some RegularExpression

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm try to efine some regular expression

```
String passwordPattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";
String imageFileExtensionPattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";
String HTMLtagPattern="<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>";
String ExtractHTMLlinkPattern="\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*(\"([^"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+))";
```

But Eclipse doesn't compile and say me `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )`

also with Official W3C email regular expression (RFC2822) get the same error

```
 String emailPattern="(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|”(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*”)@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Java treats `\` as an escape character within string literals, you need to escape the them in your patterns, so they will be interpreted as part of the regular expression (instead of a normal escaped character):

```
String passwordPattern="((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";
String imageFileExtensionPattern="([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";
String HTMLtagPattern="<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";
String ExtractHTMLlinkPattern="\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
```

Comment: thanks but.. still same problem in HTMLtagPattern and ExtractHTMLlinkPattern

Comment: @AndreaF; you need to use '\\' for a backslash in *any* string.

Comment: @AndreaF You also need to use `\"` to represent a double quote to within a string. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *escape* the backslashes: i.e. write `\\` instead of `\`.

`\` is used in string literals for special characters: e.g. `\t` is a tab. So if you want an actual backslash you need to write `\\`

Comment: I can accept only an answer however an up vote is also for you ;)

Comment: A good choice - I too upvoted it - mainly because it also mentions `\"`

Answer (score 0):

If Java uses C++ style string quoting, double quotes and escapes need to be escaped (or trigraphs, which might be MS specific).

If so, these should be the new strings. One of the regexes already had " escaped.
The last regex has some `”` quotes.
I used *RegexFormat* to format each to examine, then to pack them into C-style strings.

```
 passwordPattern="((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";
 imageFileExtensionPattern="([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)"
 HTMLtagPattern="<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";
 ExtractHTMLlinkPattern="\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
 emailPattern="(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|”(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*”)@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";


 (?:
      [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
      (?: \. [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ )*
   |  ”
      (?:
           [\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f] 
        |  \\ [\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f] 
      )*
      ”
 )
 @
 (?:
      (?:
           [a-z0-9] 
           (?: [a-z0-9-]* [a-z0-9] )?
           \.
      )+
      [a-z0-9] 
      (?: [a-z0-9-]* [a-z0-9] )?
   |  \[
      (?:
           (?:
                25 [0-5] 
             |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
             |  [01]? [0-9] [0-9]? 
           )
           \.
      ){3}
      (?:
           25 [0-5] 
        |  2 [0-4] [0-9] 
        |  [01]? [0-9] [0-9]? 
        |  [a-z0-9-]* [a-z0-9] :
           (?:
                [\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f] 
             |  \\ [\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f] 
           )+
      )
      \]
 )
```